# How can I get a custom output using winston in combination with simple()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I am trying to get the following format using winston: `2020-01-01 [INFO]: test` having the level part colorized, instead I am getting

`info: test`

How can I get the format I am looking for?

```js
import winston from "winston";

const format = winston.format.combine(
  winston.format.align(),
  winston.format.colorize(),
  winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
  winston.format.printf(
    ({ level, message }) => `[${level.toUpperCase()}]: ${message}`
  ),
  winston.format.simple(),
  winston.format.timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" })
);

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "info" : "debug",
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console({ format })],
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed using the following

```js
import winston from "winston";

const format = winston.format.combine(
  winston.format(info => ({ ...info, level: info.level.toUpperCase() }))(),
  winston.format.align(),
  winston.format.colorize(),
  winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
  winston.format.prettyPrint(),
  winston.format.simple(),
  winston.format.splat(),
  winston.format.timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" }),
  winston.format.printf(
    ({ timestamp, level, message }) => `${timestamp} [${level}]: ${message}`
  )
);

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "info" : "debug",
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console({ format })],
});
```